# Setting a ReferenceProperty to None. Will it raise an exception?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model with a property of type ReferenceProperty, I want to be able to filter by entities that don't have this property. You can't filter by  or  but you can by None like this:

```
Entity.all().filter('property =', None)
```

Is it possible to set ReferenceProperties to None? Or will it raise an exception because None is not considered of the same type as the object referenced to in the property's definition?

Wasn't able to find out the answer in the docs here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
>>> e = Entity()
>>> e.ref = None
>>> e.put()
>>> # wait few secs for datastore to complete write op
>>> e.key() in [e.key() for e in Entity.all().filter('ref =', None)]
True
```